# iOS9 alertView does not appear when "no sim card" alertview showing

Tags: ios, ios9, uialertview, uialertcontroller

My App will show an alertView when a Request fail.

1. When the app sending request,I make the app to **background**.
2. And then I take out the SIM card.
   iPhone shows an alertView:"**no sim card**".(don't press OK)
3. And now the app will show a AlertView at Background.
4. Then I press OK (on the SIM card alertView),and turn the app in foreground.

I found that the `alertView` **does not appear**. **but It's there!** It covered screen,I can't touch anything else!

I try `UIAlertView` and `UIAlertController`, but I failed.

I print out the VCs,find the `UIAlertControllerView` been hidden.

> (lldb) pvc
>       , state: appeared, view: 
>          + , state: appeared, view: <_UIAlertControllerView 0x142aa4000>, presented with:
>   <_UIAlertControllerAlertPresentationController 0x142a74d80>
>        (lldb) po 0x142aa4000
>       <_UIAlertControllerView: 0x142aa4000; frame = (52.5 270.5; 270 126); hidden = YES; gestureRecognizers = ; layer
>   = >

device Version:iOS 9.1

Is it a bug with iOS 9.1? or what can I fix this?

Comment: can you edit this question to use "alertView" everywhere instead of "alterView"? The title is really confusing now.

Comment: interesting edge case. Maybe try to refresh your views when coming back to foreground (setNeedsLayout)?